# What equation will answer how many point to point connections are possible?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, discrete-mathematics, random-variables, recurrence-relations

If the four points in a square has a maximum of 6 different one-to-one connections, (or 5 points has a max of 10 connection) how many would/could, for example, 12 individual points make, or any number, and what equation shows that, in Python?

// (I asked this in the python forum, but in stackexchange tradition they closed it, and sent me here. I assume to find the equation, and assumably then go back there and ask with the function in tow.)

Comment: To make a connection you need 2 points, so it is pick 2 of 12. That is a problem of combinatorics. Search it a little bit.

Comment: thank you, i was struggling to name it, i was focusing on 2n-2

Answer (score 1):

The number of connections is $$\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$ where $n$ denotes the number of points.

Comment: n and 2 are just the declared int/var in the set?

Answer (score 1):

The "point to point" connections as you count them are simply the pairs of points.  So use the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{2}$ to count the number of ways to choose two things out of $n$:

$$ \binom{n}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} $$

Comment: the binomial is like a Sigma notation, it doesn't have to be solved?

Comment: There is no Sigma notation.  See the formula above, which is all you need to calculate for $n$ points.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Represent a connection as a pair of points $(a,b)$. If you have a total of $n$ points, in how many ways can you choose $a$? Once you have $a$, in how many ways can you choose a *different* $b$? Note that in this way you are counting both $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$, so ... ?

Comment: which explains why the variable to be counted is n-1, based on the other answers, so that i don't repeat the primary variable?